# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii'

Tags: python, unicode, character, encode

Sorry guys I'm really new at this.. Here is the full python script.

The purpose of the script is to read two different 1 wire temperature sensors and then use HTTP post to write those values into a mysql database.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import hashlib
import time

#Dont forget to fill in PASSWORD and URL TO saveTemp (twice) in this file

sensorids = ["28-00000", "28-000004"]
avgtemperatures = []
for sensor in range(len(sensorids)):
    temperatures = []
    for polltime in range(0,3):
            text = '';
            while text.split("\n")[0].find("YES") == -1:
                    # Open the file that we viewed earlier so that python can see what          is in it. Replace the serial number as before.
                    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/"+ sensorids[sensor] +"/w1_slave")
                    # Read all of the text in the file.
                    text = tfile.read()
                    # Close the file now that the text has been read.
                    tfile.close()
                    time.sleep(1)

            # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line.
            secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
            # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0).
            temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
            # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number.
            temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
            # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it.
            temperatures.append(temperature / 1000 * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0)

    avgtemperatures.append(sum(temperatures) / float(len(temperatures)))

print avgtemperatures[0]
print avgtemperatures[1]

session = requests.Session()
# Getting a fresh nonce which we will use in the authentication step.
nonce = session.get(url='http://127.0.0.1/temp/saveTemp.php?step=nonce').text

# Hashing the nonce, the password and the temperature values (to provide some integrity).
response = hashlib.sha256('{}PASSWORD{}{}'.format(nonce.encode('utf8'), *avgtemperatures).hexdigest())

# Post data of the two temperature values and the authentication response.
post_data = {'response':response, 'temp1':avgtemperatures[0], 'temp2': avgtemperatures[1]}

post_request = session.post(url='http://127.0.0.1/temp/saveTemp.php', data=post_data)

if post_request.status_code == 200 :
    print post_request.text
```

Below is the NEW error that I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/pollSensors.py", line 42, in <module>
response = hashlib.sha256('{}PASSWORD{}{}'.format(nonce.encode('utf8'), *avgtemperatures).hexdigest())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'
```

Comment: And what are `nonce` and `avgtemperatures` exactly? Please do give us something we can reproduce your problem with.

Comment: Your problem is entirely independent of MySQL.

Comment: I added the full script to the original post.

Comment: `nonce` is unicode; you used `session.get(...).text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nonce` is a unicode value; `session.get(..).text` is always unicode.

You are trying to force that value into a string without explicitly providing an encoding. As a result Python is trying to encode it for you with the default ASCII codec. That encoding is failing.

Encode your Unicode values to strings explicitly instead. For a SHA 256 hash, UTF-8 is probably fine.

```
response = hashlib.sha256(nonce.encode('utf8') + 'PASSWORD' +
                          str(avgtemperatures[0]) +
                          str(avgtemperatures[1])).hexdigest()
```

or use string templating:

```
response = hashlib.sha256('{}PASSWORD{}{}'.format(
    nonce.encode('utf8'), *avgtemperatures)).hexdigest()
```

Comment: I added the following below to the top of the python script and the error changed.. 
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

New error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/pollSensors.py", line 42, in <module>
    response =(nonce + 'PASSWORD' + str(avgtemperatures[0]) + str(avgtemperatures[1])).hexdigest()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'

Comment: @user2782497: the `coding` header is not the cause of that, nor could it have been. You removed the `hashlib.sha256` call there.

Comment: I updated the original post to show the updated code and new error.. At least the error is changing!

Comment: @user2782497: My mistake, missing closing parenthesis on the `response = ` line.

Comment: Thanks Martijn.. That fixed the syntax error.. New error is in the original post.

Comment: @user2782497: you put the closing parenthesis in the *wrong place*. Copy my code exactly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue except that it was decimal instead of ascci

remove  directory: your-profile.spyder2\spyder.lock